# How to enable/disable button to prevent repeated playing of audio in Kivy?

Tags: python, audio, kivy

I am making an app in Kivy, and I have managed to bind audio to a button. I have had a problem earlier regarding overlapping audio (i.e. when the button is pressed for the second or more times while the audio is still playing), for which I have found a solution.

I've added `instance.disabled = True` to the code, and as a result there's no more overlapping audio since the button is disabled after pressing once. But, after the audio is finished playing, and if I press the button again to play the audio for the second time, it will not play. Kindly help . Thanks.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class MySound(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,*kwargs):
        super().__init__(*kwargs)

        self.btn1 = Button(text = "Press Me",size_hint = (0.3,0.3),
                            pos_hint={"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5})
        self.btn1.bind(on_press = self.SoundPlayer)
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)


    def SoundPlayer(self,instance):
        sound = SoundLoader.load("clip.mp3")
        sound.play()
        instance.disabled = True


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MySound()

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: From what I can see, you are not setting the instance to be enabled again. I'm not very familiar with kivy, but according to the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html) you can either check for the state and set the instance to be enabled again when the state changes to stopped, or write a simple event handler for when the audio changes to stopped(AudioPlayer.on_stop)

Comment: You can bind a callback function to the property `state` (of audio) to manage the button.